# Type matching unparameterised Java List in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to set a mock expectation in a test in Scala. The mock is on the Hibernate Query object. It has the method:

```
List list() throws HibernateException;
```

The List is not parameterised.

When I try to mock this I can't get the types right. E.g.

```
when(query.list).thenReturn(new ArrayList)
when(query.list).thenReturn(new ArrayList[Any])
// and other variations
```

Report:

```
overloaded method value thenReturn with alternatives: 
(java.util.List[?0],<repeated...>[java.util.List[?0]])org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[java.util.List[?0]] <and> 
(java.util.List[?0])org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[java.util.List[?0]] 
cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.Object])
```

What should my Scala mock expectation look like?

Comment: From memory you should write: `when(query.list.asInstanceOf[ArrayList[Any]]).thenReturn(new ArrayList[Any])` but I can't check it right now so I'm not proposing this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `asInstanceOf` cast and write:

```
when(query.list.asInstanceOf[ArrayList[Any]]).thenReturn(new ArrayList[Any])
```